# Ethernet Port of router works but the wifi connection says no internet conenction

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ethernet, lan, modem

I am having problems with connecting both a tv that recieves cable via a an ethernet conection and my wifi router. I have the following setup, on my main house I have a fiber optic modem with 4 lan out connections. One of those lan connections goes directly to a dlink switch. So this is the problem , I have another router a tplink in an adjacent house, conencted to this router is a tv , this tv works via ethernet cable , when I connect this router directly to the switch in my main house the wifi on this tplink router works but the tv connected to one of the ports on the tplink router doesnt work. When I connect the tplink router directly to the main modem lans port the tv connected to the tplink works , but no the wifi internet conenction. One or the other works , but not both.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure router 1 has **DCHP server turned on**.  part 1 Step 6

Make sure router 2 has **DCHP server turned off**.  part 2 step 4

Essentially you may have DCHP server turned on for both routers.  You only need it for the first one, and not the 2nd router connected to the first router.

step by step here:
https://www.wikihow.com/Connect-One-Router-to-Another-to-Expand-a-Network

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the other post, having only one DHCP server is very important.

Also important is the physical hookup - normally LAN to LAN as your modem has its own built in router (you wrote "I have a fiber optic modem with 4 LAN out connections")

It is also a good idea to give other routers a Static IP Address on the main network. Do this in the LAN settings of the router setup. Having a static IP prevents the routers from getting lost in the case of a soft reset from a power outage.

I have posted a simple diagram below to assist you with these concepts. I have done numerous setups like this and the approach is robust and works fine.

[image]